# checkbox checking based on list

Tags: jquery, checkbox, angularjs

I am using angularjs v0.9 to implement my membership beta system...

Currently, I have two controllers...

```
var selected = []
function Ctrl1(){
    checkCheckboxesByIds(selected );
    //users will select a list of values from checkboxes..
    $('#renewlist input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });    
}

function Ctrl2(){
//call an api function with "selected"
}
```

however, in the html of Ctrl2, it gives the user a choice to move back to the previous if he or she has selected a checkbox wrongly..

I have googled and found this function

```
function checkCheckboxesByIds(ids) {
 $.each(ids, function(i, id) {
    $('#member-' + id).attr('checked', 'checked'); 
 });
}
```

However, this only works 75% of the time. If I repeatedly click back and forward, the checkboxes will sometimes fail to be checked...

Is there anyway I can make it more foolproof??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you are using jQuery 1.6+ - You should really be using `.prop('checked',true/false)` to set the checked property

Comment: 1) NEVER manipulate the DOM inside of controllers. 2) Why are you using angular 0.9? Why do not use the last version? It change very much since 0.9

Comment: @RenanTomalFernandes Hmm. I didn't know there was a latest version until recently and am at the end of my project. Where can I manipulate DOM if not inside the controller?? onload on body of the html?

Comment: @Wilson You should write DOM logic in a directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @wirey

I really should be using .prop('checked', true) to set the checked property.

```
function checkCheckboxesByIds(ids) {
 $.each(ids, function(i, id) {
    $('#member-' + id).prop('checked',true); 
 });
}
```

It is still not foolproof because the sixth time I submit and return, the checkboxes will not be checked. But this is good enough for my purpose.

Thank you.